# PHP - Inserting an if statement within a variable (if post field is blank)

Tags: php

I need a variable to be set as if the posted field is empty then leave the variable blank, else if it is populated put the value plus a hyphen in front of it.

I made this code but it didn't work:

```
$xCartLettuce = if (empty($_POST['Lettuce'])) {""); } else {strtoupper("-".$_POST['Lettuce']."");};
```

Comment: Use ternary operator. `$xCartLettuce = empty($_POST['Lettuce']) ? "" : strtoupper("-".$_POST['Lettuce']."");` See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Are you looking to use a ternary operator? Or are you really not sure how to form an `if` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ternary operator:

```
$xCartLettuce = empty($_POST['Lettuce'])? "" : strtoupper("-".$_POST['Lettuce']."");
```

Comment: I'd prefer `isset()` to avoid a `E_NOTICE` if the index does not exist.

Comment: You'll be suprised but `empty` will not emit notice too.

Comment: I'm confused. Just checked. Perhaps it has something to do with `berenstain` vs `berenstein`. All these years... I had it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[Click here to read about Ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#PHP)

```
$xCartLettuce = empty($_POST['Lettuce']) ? "" : "-".strtoupper($_POST['Lettuce']);
```

Comment: Sorry, I had it wrong. Been put on my place by [chris85](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750323/php-inserting-an-if-statement-within-a-variable-if-post-field-is-blank/42750351?noredirect=1#comment72617026_42750351). Using `empty()` will give the better results.